# Compile error Argument not optional

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code I ran before on a temporary computer and ran perfectly but it seems I can't get it to run on this machine even if I reference suggested by the author

I get

> Compile error Argument not optional

on `Sub kl()`

```
Sub kl()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim htlm As HTMLDocument
Dim link As Object
Dim links As Object
Dim erow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate = "http://www.google.com"

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "loading website"
    DoEvents
Loop

Set Html = ie.document
Set links = Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In links
    erow = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(erow, 1).Value = link
    Cells(erow, 1).Columns.AutoFit
Next

Set.ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
Application.screenupdate = True

End Sub
```

Any help on why it's causing error? Ive referenced MSXML, ActiveX Library, MSHTML and MS Internet Controls

I get error for ie.navigate = "http://www.google.com"

Working code :

```
Sub kl()
Dim ie As Object
Dim htlm As HTMLDocument
Dim link As Object
Dim links As Object
Dim erow As Long

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.google.com"


Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "loading website"
DoEvents
Loop

 Set HTML = ie.document
 Set links = HTML.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In links
erow = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1).Value = link
Cells(erow, 1).Columns.AutoFit
Next

Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: `Set ie = New InternetExplorer` ...can you do that? Perhaps try `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. Also, unrelated, but you should include the sheet name before `Cells()` too, e.g. ` Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(erow, 1)...`

Comment: `ie.Navigate` expects a parameter, it isn't something you can set equal to something else.  So `ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"`.

Comment: And before you change the question yet again `Set.ie = Nothing` should be `Set ie = Nothing`.

Comment: It gave error when I changed it on "Set .ie = Nothing" and added a space Compile error : invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: Well, change it back to `Set.ie = Nothing` if you like, but you will then need to declare an object variable called `Set` and, because that is an object, you will probably have to say `Set Set.ie = Nothing` - but none of that makes sense.  It should be `Set ie = Nothing`.

Comment: Thank the help ive deleted the period "Set ie = Nothing", but "Application.screenupdate = True" run-time error object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: Sigh - compare `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.screenupdate = True` - what looks different (apart from `False` and `True`)?

Comment: Very nice, ive gone ahead and deleted the screen update as its one webpage i will use it for, check updated code

Comment: I didn't mean you had to delete it - I meant for you to compare the two properties (`Application.ScreenUpdating` and `Application.screenupdate`) and see the typo.

Comment: I will be for troubleshooting, be adding screen update in the future, thanks everyone.

Comment: `Dim htlm As HTMLDocument` seems to be misspelt.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is in how you're creating and calling the Internet Explorer application.

Try this instead:

```
...
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.google.com"  ' This seems to be the main thing, don't use `=`
...
```

Comment: The creation of IE is probably fine (or, at least, it **should** be), but the `=` in `ie.navigate = "http://www.google.com"` would be causing the syntax error.